# Decoding weird symbols in a text file

Tags: text-files, decode, symbols

One of my text files has become seemingly encrypted with strange symbols such as
���,
ל�9I,

I'm wondering if there's a way to decode this? I've looked around for different ways and thought I was getting close a few times but I never found anything.
This is for a personal college project so Im hoping there's a way to convert this to a human readable form?

Comment: What are you using to view the file? If you are on Windows try to avoid Notepad or Wordpad. Download Notepad++ or something that can handle different encodings - this may show these characters correctly.

Comment: I've tried using notepad++ but I get the same. It doesn't display on chromebook either. I've tried all sorts of different encoding translations and none have worked so far.